# References for z/OS and DB2 performance tuning

Tags: db2, mainframe, zos

I need references for z/OS and DB2 performance tuning.

Comment: "Please press Caps Lock" - "THANKS ITS SO MUCH EASIER NOW"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All normal documentation is help on the Boulder publib site ([DB2/z](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp) and [z/OS](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/zos/basics/index.jsp)). Other than that, you should be looking into [IBM RedBooks](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/). IBM invests a lot of time and money into putting those together.

Answer (score 0):

If you want outside help, you can not go wrong with [InnovizeIT.biz](http://www.innovizeIT.biz), a unique tool and service to find hidden performance sinks on DB2 z/OS.

Disclosure - I am the InnovizeIT VP R&D :-)